# how to adjust image to fit whole width and height?

Tags: css

I have a problem with my sprites not occupying the whole width for my container with 100% width? obviously images on my image sprites have different sizes but I cannot make an image reference fit to the width of the container and there is that weird white space as content?

i think making them same size will fix the problem but do I have to do that with image sprites?

this is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iamglenbacs/9fhmfog0/1/) and my code

```
 html,
 body {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.slider {
 width: 600px;
 height: 400px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 border: solid;
}
/* demo test purpose*/
.slider>div {/* see me */
 box-shadow:0 0 0 1px ;
}
 .slider #img1  {
    background: url('https://s31.postimg.org/hxrherccb/sprites.png') no-repeat 0 0;
    background-size: cover;
  width: 600px;
  height:400px;
  }
 .slider #img2 {
 background: url('https://s31.postimg.org/hxrherccb/sprites.png') no-repeat 0 25.026%;
 background-size: cover;
 width: 100%;
 height:100%;
 }
 .slider #img3 {
 background: url('https://s31.postimg.org/hxrherccb/sprites.png') no-repeat  0 12.87%;
 background-size: cover;
 width: 100%;
 height:100%;
 }
 .slider #img4 {
 background: url('https://s31.postimg.org/hxrherccb/sprites.png') no-repeat 0 33.65%;
 background-size: cover;
 width: 100%;
 height:100%;
 }
```

Comment: Well to start with, images in the sprite need to be the same dimension each. They also need to be at least as big as the parent container. Can I use a random sprite I find on google and show you an example of how it's done?

Comment: yes, please. I'd really appreciate. if it'll do the task. I'd accept your answer

Comment: It will, sprites need to be very specific. I'll post an answer.

Comment: your sprite image  is not even on the right side. Have a look at it https://s31.postimg.org/hxrherccb/sprites.png

Comment: @coding_spy I don't understand your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example I quickly drew up. Honestly, it wasn't your code, you were just using a bad sprite sheet. When creating a sprite sheet, make sure all images are the exact same dimension. Set the image element's dimensions to be the same as the image in the sprite (You'll have to specify width and height with pixels). That's really all there is to it.

Hope this helps.

```css
.slider {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.slide {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background-size: 1022px 755px !important;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.slider .slide:nth-child(1) {
  background: url('http://orig11.deviantart.net/1e13/f/2014/314/b/a/high_quality_paper_mario_sprites_by_fawfulthegreat64-d860r1v.png');  
}

.slider .slide:nth-child(2) {
  background: url('http://orig11.deviantart.net/1e13/f/2014/314/b/a/high_quality_paper_mario_sprites_by_fawfulthegreat64-d860r1v.png'); 
  background-position: 246px 0;
}
.slider .slide:nth-child(3) {
  background: url('http://orig11.deviantart.net/1e13/f/2014/314/b/a/high_quality_paper_mario_sprites_by_fawfulthegreat64-d860r1v.png'); 
  background-position: 365px 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul class="slider">
      <li class="slide"></li>
      <li class="slide"></li>
      <li class="slide"></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `100vh` and `100vw` instead of the `100%` :)

Comment: a fiddle would be much appreciated. it doesn't work on me. I only want them to fit on the borders perfectly

Comment: [This](https://jsfiddle.net/9fhmfog0/5/) is the same code just with different images from google images :)

Comment: [Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9fhmfog0/6/) removing the margin/white space on the left

Comment: I think the question is specific to a sprite sheet, not a regular image.

Comment: Gotcha, I misunderstood the question then...hopefully this version still helps someone out!